# Flutter - Connect trust wallet using wallet connect

Tags: flutter, wallet-connect, trustwallet

I am trying to create a mobile app that can connect to mobile wallets (ex: Metamask, TrustWalet,...) via WalletConnect, but i can't find anything.

Is there any way to implement walletconnect on flutter app yet?

Comment: Hi @viet hoang did you get any solutions for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You need [walletconnect_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart) and [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';
import 'package:walletconnect_dart/walletconnect_dart.dart';


// Create a connector
final connector = WalletConnect(
    bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
    clientMeta: PeerMeta(
      name: 'WalletConnect',
      description: 'WalletConnect Developer App',
      url: 'https://walletconnect.org',
      icons: [
        'https://gblobscdn.gitbook.com/spaces%2F-LJJeCjcLrr53DcT1Ml7%2Favatar.png?alt=media'
      ],
    ),
);

// Subscribe to events
connector.on('connect', (session) => print(session));
connector.on('session_update', (payload) => print(payload));
connector.on('disconnect', (session) => print(session));

// Create a new session
if (!connector.connected) {
    final session = await connector.createSession(
        onDisplayUri: (uri) async {
        _uri = uri;
        await launchUrlString(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
      }
    );
}
```

For more information please visit [walletconnect_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart)

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  wallet_connect: ^1.0.2
```

---

```
  final wcClient = WCClient(
      onConnect: () {
        // Respond to connect callback
      },
      onDisconnect: (code, reason) {
        // Respond to disconnect callback
      },
      onFailure: (error) {
        // Respond to connection failure callback
      },
      onSessionRequest: (id, peerMeta) {
        // Respond to connection request callback
      },
      onEthSign: (id, message) {
        // Respond to personal_sign or eth_sign or eth_signTypedData request callback
      },
      onEthSendTransaction: (id, tx) {
        // Respond to eth_sendTransaction request callback
      },
      onEthSignTransaction: (id, tx) {
        // Respond to eth_signTransaction request callback
      },
    );
```

---

For More Check : [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/wallet_connect)

Comment: Sorry, I think that implementation is building a wallet app themselves, not for dapps that want to connect to a wallet.